# Setting 'Default' keychain for another user on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, authentication, keychain

I am having trouble logging in to my usual admin account on my Mac OSX running Lion. Here's what happened:

- I have two user-accounts on my mac (let's say MyAccount and Dummy)
- I created a new keychain in Keychain Access MyAccount to test out something and set it to Default
- I then logged in to Dummy and did some work there
- I later came back to MyAccount and deleted the new Default keychain and went back to Dummy to continue what I was doing
- I then shut down the mac and tried logging in to MyAccount but I keep looping back to the log-in screen
- I tried turning on the root user from Dummy but how do I go about from there?
- I am guess since I deleted the new keychain and did not set "login" to default, this messed up something
- How do I log in to MyAccount now ?

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/