# iOS default keychain for unprivileged user used to start Tomcat and Jenkins

Tags: ios, macos, security, jenkins, keychain

I have an unprivileged user that I created to start Tomcat 8 as a service.  Tomcat runs Jenkins, which is used to provide jobs where members of my team can upload an .ipa file and a provisioning profile and re-sign the .ipa file.  Jenkins is running a shell script whenever it re-signs the .ipa file.  That shell script was recently updated and now calls the security command, which results in the following error:

> security: cert import failed: a default keychain could not be found.

I need to set the default keychain for my unprivileged Tomcat user.

How can I do that?  I don't see much on the web about it, and I see another, unanswered StackOverflow post regarding the topic.

Comment: Just in case, here is the other SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693857/setting-default-keychain-for-another-user-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is a better solution.  I was able to use the following to dynamically create a new keychain, add a cert to the keychain, and later remove the keychain:

```
security create-keychain -p temp "temp.keychain"
security add-certificates -k "temp.keychain" "ios_distribution.cer"
security unlock-keychain -p temp "temp.keychain"

security cms -D -k "temp.keychain" -i "blah.mobileprovision" > <entitlements>

...do some stuff...

security delete-keychain -h "temp.keychain"
```

If you do want to set the keychain for an unprivileged user, you can use the following command:

```
default-keychain [-h] [-d user|system|common|dynamic] [-s [keychain]]
```

Ex.

```
default-keychain -h "temp.keychain"
```

You can run that command from a shell script that is being executed by the unprivileged user (as I am doing).